# Acrylic Sphere Thickness

Tags: pressure, water

How do I figure out how thick the walls of an acrylic sphere need to be to withstand water pressure at a certain depth?

Comment: Actually, I suspect there may be quite an accurate theory of failure that would be, to first order, independent of the detailed properties of the acrylic and dependent only on the thickness and elastic modulus and this would be analogous to the stability analysis that foretells pretty accurately the [catastrophic buckling of columns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckling).

Answer (score 3):

Further to [Farcher's Answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/270845/26076), which is "correct", I suspect in practice there might be an elastic buckling theory foretelling "critical" implosion pressures lower than those that one would naïvely think would lead to failure grounded on yield stress figures and the like as in Farcher's answer.

The study of implosion buckling, together with original references, can be found in:

[C. Farhata, K.G. Wang, A. Main, S. Kyriakides, , L.-H. Leed, K. Ravi-Chandar, T. Belytschko, "Dynamic implosion of underwater cylindrical shells: Experiments and Computations", International Journal of Solids and Structures, **50** 2013](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002076831300200X)

This is analogous to the stability analysis that foretells pretty accurately the [catastrophic buckling of elastic columns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckling).

For simplicity, let's think of a 2D problem where a cylinder is being crushed by outside pressure. Analogous with buckling theory, you would use Euler-Bernoulli beam theory to describe possible equilibrium shapes of the cylinder for various pressures. You might begin with a cylinder with a vacuum within for a conservative, easy beginning, then build your theory up to include the effects of pressurized gas within.

What you would find would be that, below a critical pressure depending on the cylinder's Young's modulus and the thickness, the only solution for the cylinder's cross section would be a circle.

At a critical pressure, a "multifurcation" happens where not only is a circle a possible solution, but other "flower-like" solutions where sinusoidal deviations from circularity show up around the circumference (similar to the "resonance" constraints envisaged for the electron orbits in the Bohr atom): the deviations would be of the form $A\,\sin(n\,\theta) +  B\,\cos(n\,\theta)$ for integral $n$, where $\theta$ is the polar angle measuring the position on the circumference.

The appearance of multiple solutions at critical pressures signals equilibria that can be upset to deform catastrophically into one another. In practice the minimum such pressure is going to be pretty near to the pressure that will implode your cylinder.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a "perfect" spherical shell of radius $r$ and thickness $t$.
For a simple analysis assume $r\gg t$.
Cut the shell in half then the area of the exposed flat surface of the hemispherical shell is approximately $2 \pi r t$.
The force acting on this surface area due to the excess outside pressure $P$ is $P \pi r^2$.

So the compressive stress in the flat surface is $  \dfrac {P\pi r^2}{2 \pi rt}= \dfrac {Pr}{2t}$.

A value of the compressive yield strength of acrylic is given [here](http://www.matweb.com/reference/compressivestrength.aspx) as 95 MPa.

The approximation made that there is only one type of stress at work is reasonable if the radius of the shell is at least 10 times the thickness of the shell and of course the analysis assumes that the shell and the material of which it is made does not have any imperfections.

Comment: And if you value whatever is in there, double, if not quadruple the max. pressure. :-)

Comment: I am told that British Victorian engineers worked to a factor of safety of at least 5 although that did not necessarily stop disasters happening. :-))

Comment: Well, I would have done the same with products and materials made in GB... :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne Ouch, I hope John Rennie doesn't see this one. One could say much the same for most stuff made in my home land too. Anyhow, I suspect that the Victorian safety factors were needed to account for buckling effects, as in my "answer".

Comment: Compressive yield strength is not relevant, because it just means the sphere shrinks.   It doesn't mean failure of the structure (but it won't spring back fully, as if THAT is important).

Comment: @Whit3rd I agree but I could not fond a value for the ultimate compressive strength of acrylic and so gave a value for the onset of plastic deformation which is going to be less than the ultimate strength.

Answer (score 0):

It would have a lot to do with the size of the ball and the ratio of it's thickness to radius and the elasticity of material.
It will gradually shrink up to a certain depth depending on how round and even thickness it is. But ultimately it will collapse explosively in a mechanism similar to a column buckling due to unstable balance! If the material is flexible enough to accept a shape like donut the shrinkage will continue till the ball is flattened into a pancake with few random bubbles of air.

Answer (score -1):

You can't calculate it.   A uniform spherical shell will shrink slightly under pressure.  Under great pressure, it'll just shrink MORE.   Unless there's a nonuniformity of
the acrylic, it won't fail by fracture, just get smaller...

It's possible, for instance, that the first damage done will be by spontaneous
oxidation due to the compressed oxygen in the central void.

There's a useful submarine item, called 'syntactic foam' that uses lots of glass microspheres for reliable flotation.

Comment: Actually, I suspect there may be quite an accurate theory of failure that would be, to first order, independent of the detailed properties of the acrylic and dependent only on the thickness and elastic modulus and this would be analogous to the stability analysis that foretells pretty accurately the [catastrophic buckling of columns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckling).

Comment: Buckling might never occur.   If it requires the sphere to become nonspheric, recall that pressure favors minimum volume, and the sphere IS minimum volume.   That's why syntactic foam was chosen for bathyscaphes, microspheres don''t fail under pressure.

Comment: That's a good point about the minimum surface area for given volume, but I think it's only good for a system where the inside and outside pressures are equal. This probably won't happen with a rigid acrylic plastic.When there's a pressure difference, you can still reach a lower energy state with a buckled deformation. I think you'll find that the spherical structure will give you the minimum required wall thickness. The microspheres in the foam itself won't fail because they can equilibrate as you validly describe in your answer. But a bathscaphe itself will eventually fail ....

Comment: .... because it's supporting a pressure difference.

Comment: When a bathyscaphe fails under pressure, it's likely because it is NOT symmetric.  A buckling of a sphere has to start with a local flattening, and only is driven forward when the local flat area turns concave; that isn't a small fluctuation, like curving a pillar for Euler buckling.   I'm remembering the Seth Neddermeyer experiments on explosive pressure around a cylinder: the cylinder turned from a neutron absorber to net emitter before it buckled significantly.

Comment: There is always asymmetry: the point about buckling theory, or indeed any stability analysis is that it looks at the stability of equilibrium points in the face of *arbitrarily small* perturbations to that equilibrium: *i.e.* whether or not perturbations beget dynamic trajectories that stay within a bounded neighborhood of the equilibrium, or whether the paths have positive Lyapunov exponents and grow without bound. And the sphere, like anything else has a bifurcation point. I'm not sure that implosion of a plutonium pit is a good example: this is a highly dynamic system and very short lived.

Comment: Also, if you have an online reference to the Neddermeyer experiments, that would be good.

Comment: The Euler column has no first-order response to curvature, only second derivative.  A sphere, on the other hand, has a first-order (elastic) response to flattening (that's why balls bounce) so it's unclear that a second derivative will EVER dominate.   Like a bicycle wheel, it isn't pressure on the spokes that keeps the wheel round, it's the arch of the rim that makes it stiff.   For a bit on Seth and his experiments, rent _Fat_Man_and_Little_ Boy_.   Heck, rent Hud too, and see a Paul Newman double feature.